# To convert from objects of objects to array of objects

Tags: json, laravel, api, laravel-8, response

I have this method it produces an after-the-call of an API  method and the response JSON  which is objects of objects but I want to get a response that is an array of objects

```
     public function TODreport($school_id, $date)
{
$school = School::where('id', $school_id)->first();
$school_education_level = $school->educationLevel;
$result =['message' => 'Attendance Report in School'];


$levels = [
    'Standard One', 'Standard Two', 'Standard Three', 'Standard Four',
    'Standard Five', 'Standard Six', 'Standard Seven',
];

if($school_education_level == 'Secondary') {
    $levels = ['Form One', 'Form Two', 'Form Three', 'Form Four'];
}
foreach($levels as $level) {
   $result['grades'][$level] = [];

    $result['grades'][$level]['total_students'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->count();

    $result['grades'][$level]['total_boys_present_in_class'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('attendance_id', "1")
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->whereHas('student' , function($query){
            return $query->where('gender', 'male');
        })
        ->count();

    $result['grades'][$level]['total_girls_present_in_class'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('attendance_id', "1")
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->whereHas('student' , function($query){
            return $query->where('gender', 'female');
        })
        ->count();

    $result['grades'][$level]['total_boys_absent_in_class'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('attendance_id', "2")
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->whereHas('student' , function($query){
            return $query->where('gender', 'male');
        })
        ->count();

    $result['grades'][$level]['total_girls_absent_in_class'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('attendance_id', "2")
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->whereHas('student' , function($query){
            return $query->where('gender', 'female');
        })
        ->count();

}
```

the result am getting is  bellow

```
 {
   "message": "Attendance Report in School",
"grades": {
    "Form One": {
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    "Form Two": {
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    "Form Three": {
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    "Form Four": {
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    }
},
"total_students_in_school": 0,
"total_present_students": 0,
"total_boys_present": 0,
"total_girls_present": 0,
"total_absent_students": 0,
"total_boys_absent": 0,
"total_girls_absent": 0
```

}

and the desired response output is here below

```
{
"message": "Attendance Report in School",
"grades": [
    "Form One": {
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    "Form Two": {
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    "Form Three": {
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    "Form Four": {
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    }
],
"total_students_in_school": 0,
"total_present_students": 0,
"total_boys_present": 0,
"total_girls_present": 0,
"total_absent_students": 0,
"total_boys_absent": 0,
"total_girls_absent": 0
```

}

please may i know where is the problem in my codes

Comment: you can't ... JSON doesn't have associative arrays, it uses objects to represent them

Comment: so is there any option to pass those grades in one key of grades

Comment: you would have to show an example of what that means to you

Comment: the json which is desired is the one below it has the key called "grades" and I want the value to be array of those grades  instead of objects of objects

Comment: JSON does not have associative arrays, it has to use objects to represent them ... so no you can't have the output you desire because it isn't valid JSON

Comment: thanks for the comments I got the solution but not exactly as you said @lagbox

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question but not exactly 100% but it so something I can use it with the code below

```
  public function TODreport($school_id, $date)
{
$school = School::where('id', $school_id)->first();
$school_education_level = $school->educationLevel;

$result =['message' => 'Attendance Report in School'];

$result['grades'] = [];

$levels = [
    'Standard One','Standard Two', 'Standard Three','Standard Four',
    'Standard Five', 'Standard Six', 'Standard Seven',
];

if($school_education_level == 'Secondary') {
    $levels = ['Form One', 'Form Two', 'Form Three', 'Form Four'];
}
foreach($levels as $level) {

    $resultii[$level] = [];

   $resultii[$level]['grade'] = $level;
   $resultii[$level]['total_students'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->count();
    $resultii[$level]['total_boys_present_in_class'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('attendance_id' , "1")
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->whereHas('student' , function($query){
            return $query->where('gender', 'male');
        })
        ->count();

    $resultii[$level]['total_girls_present_in_class'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('attendance_id' , "1")
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->whereHas('student' , function($query){
            return $query->where('gender', 'female');
        })
        ->count();

    $resultii[$level]['total_boys_absent_in_class'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('attendance_id' , "2")
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->whereHas('student' , function($query){
            return $query->where('gender', 'male');
        })
        ->count();

    $resultii[$level]['total_girls_absent_in_class'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
        ->where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('attendance_id' , "2")
        ->where('grade', $level )
        ->whereHas('student' , function($query){
            return $query->where('gender', 'female');
        })
        ->count();
       $result['grades'][]= $resultii[$level];
}


//-------total number of students called in attendance in that date-------//
  $attendanceschool_fetched  = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
    ->where('school_id', $school_id)
    ->get();
$result['total_students_in_school'] = $attendanceschool_fetched->count();
//-------total number of students called in attendance in that date-------//

//--------total present students fetched in that date-------------------------------//
$attendance_fetched_present = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
    ->where('school_id', $school_id)
    ->where('attendance_id' , "1")
    ->get();
$result['total_present_students'] = $attendance_fetched_present->count();
//--------total present students fetched in that date-------------------------------//


//---------total present boys-----------------------------------------------------//
$result['total_boys_present'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
    ->where('school_id', $school_id)
    ->where('attendance_id' , "1")
    ->whereHas('student' , function($query) {
        return $query->where('gender', 'male');
    })
    ->count();

//---------total present girls-----------------------------------------------------//
$result['total_girls_present'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
    ->where('school_id', $school_id)
    ->where('attendance_id' , "1")
    ->whereHas('student' , function($query) {
        return $query->where('gender', 'female');
    })
    ->count();

//---------------total absent students in a school-------------------------------//
$attendance_fetched_absent = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
    ->where('school_id', $school_id)
    ->where('attendance_id' , "2")
    ->get();
$result['total_absent_students'] = $attendance_fetched_absent->count();

//------------total absent boys in a school---------------------------------//
$result['total_boys_absent'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
    ->where('school_id', $school_id)
    ->where('attendance_id' , "2")
    ->whereHas('student' , function($query) {
        return $query->where('gender', 'male');
    })
    ->count();

//-----------------total absent girls in a school ---------------------------//
$result['total_girls_absent'] = AttendanceStudent::where('dateofattendance', $date)
    ->where('school_id', $school_id)
    ->where('attendance_id' , "2")
    ->whereHas('student' , function($query) {
        return $query->where('gender', 'female');
    })
    ->count();
  return response()->json($result);
  }
```

and these gave me this output as the response

```
   {
"message": "Attendance Report in School",
"grades": [
    {
        "grade": "Form One",
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    {
        "grade": "Form Two",
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    {
        "grade": "Form Three",
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    },
    {
        "grade": "Form Four",
        "total_students": 0,
        "total_boys_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_present_in_class": 0,
        "total_boys_absent_in_class": 0,
        "total_girls_absent_in_class": 0
    }
],
"total_students_in_school": 0,
"total_present_students": 0,
"total_boys_present": 0,
"total_girls_present": 0,
"total_absent_students": 0,
"total_boys_absent": 0,
"total_girls_absent": 0
  }
```